# How to get a json service in php

Tags: php, json

This is the following code i am using

```
<?php
 $contents= file_get_contents('http://skillpage.enigmateleco.net/rest/login.php?email=sri.sapna14@gmail.com&pass=12345');
        $contents = utf8_encode($contents);
        $contents_array = json_decode($contents,1);
?>
```

code is showing error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@gmail.com&pass=12345): failed to
> open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\skillbook\json1.php on line 9

Comment: i think this simply means that your server (-provider) blocks cross-domain requests from PHP.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use, CURL instead of file_get_contents

Comment: what is expected output from this link?

Comment: when following to that link, it returns json string `{"msg":"Request method not accepted"}`. Make sure that you are accessing that link correctly

Answer (score -1):

try to use this : $data = json_decode($request,true); this work only if your request is on JSON format